# Is "struct type variablename" valid as a declaration?

Tags: c++, syntax

My lecturer just astounded me by insisting that the following is a valid C++ statement:

```
struct charlistrecord *next
```

The complete condition was found in declaring a recursive datatype in C/C++ as follows:

```
typedef struct charlistrecord
{
     char data;
     struct charlistrecord *next;
} *charlist;
```

I want to know whether maybe there has been a time when this was accepted syntax or whether I've just been dumb for months of thinking I know C++.

Comment: Put a semi-colon on the end and it is completely valid.

Comment: Meh, while this may be valid, *only C programmers do this*. You should not feel bad for it. Your lecturer OTOH...

Comment: "C/C++"? Ah, that mythical nonexistent language...

Comment: I join the answers that it is valid, and some words on usage:  single linked lists are implemented in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to C++ and the assumption of typedefs, the only way to get a typed structure was via this syntax, and it was the *only* way to get a self-type-linked node.

```
struct Foo
{
    int val;
    struct Foo *link;
};
```

In C, this required  any usage of Foo to be:

```
struct Foo foo;
struct Foo *foo_ptr;
```

etc..

A typedef helped for this by doing this:

```
typedef struct Foo
{
   int val;
   struct Foo *link;
} Foo;
```

Since now you could do this:

```
Foo foo;       // same as struct Foo
Foo *foo_ptr;  // same as struct Foo *
```

Note: Using a typedef to alias a `struct Name` is not restricted to `Name` as the alias. Yo were perfectly valid to do this as well:

```
typedef struct Foo
{
    int val;
    struct Foo *link;
} Bar;
```

and now the following are doable;

```
struct Foo foo;
Bar bar;
struct Foo *fooptr = &bar;
Bar *barptr = &foo;
```

Really makes you wish you programmed in C back in the day, doesn't it ? Probably doesn't clear things up, but hopefully a little less gray.

Comment: eh thanks, I don't clearly understand what you mean from the point where you say, 'Since now you could do this' are you saying, that only after declaring the typedef in such manner can you then say `Foo *foo;` ?

Comment: @rtuner The is precisely what i'm saying. Without the typedef, `Foo` had to be prefaced with `struct`. With the typedef that last `} Foo;` is what exposes it as a named type. Btw. it could be something besides `} Foo;` as well. I can update the answer to demonstrate that if you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hangover from C. In C this is how you have to declare struct variables  and members, so it's legal in C++ for reasons of backwards compatibility. Sounds like your lecturer is a bit 'old school'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's totally valid. The word `struct` here just explicitly states that `next` is a pointer to a *structure* type named `charlistrecord`.

It's a reminiscence from C, and you might as well omit the keyword in C++, but if you want to use it, you can.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly valid, and it can even be useful if your struct's name is shadowed by a variable, like here:

```
struct C {};
int C = 0;
int a;

void foo() {
  C *a; // multiplies int C by int a
  struct C *a; //defines 'a' as pointer to struct C
}
```